# Styling z-index of Pseudo Element

Tags: angular, html, css

Currently I am working on a nav-bar menu. I want to be able to use the arrow created using `CSS borders` when hovering over my `nav` items. Currently this is working however the arrow created `:after` is currently half hidden when it goes over the `nav border`. Even when styling the z-index as seen below it is still hidden.

I can only put in a small snippet of code because otherwise it would be too much but hopefully you can see what I mean.

```css
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 50px;
}

.navbar-links {
  margin-left:10em;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0em 4em 0em 1em;
  min-width:348px;
  margin-top:auto;
  margin-bottom:auto;
}

#navbar .navbar-links a {
  display:block;
  float: left;
  color: grey;
  padding: 14px 20px 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  position:relative;
}

#navbar .navbar-links a:hover::after {
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-width: 10px 10px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey transparent;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  z-index:10;
}
```

```html
  <div id="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-links">
          <a [routerLinkActive]="['navbar-links-active']" [routerLink]="['link1']" (mouseover)="displayInsightDropDown();" (mouseleave)="hideInsightDropDown();">LINK 1</a>
          <a [routerLinkActive]="['navbar-links-active']" [routerLink]="['link2']">LINK 2</a> 
          <a [routerLinkActive]="['navbar-links-active']" [routerLink]="['link3']">LINK 3</a> 
        </div>
  </div>
```

I just want to be able to show those arrows outside of the nav box. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hidden, because it is a child element of `#navbar` for which you declared that the overflow should be hidden.

You simply have to set `overflow: visible;` on your `#navbar`.

```css
#navbar {
  overflow: visible; /* ← This does the trick */
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 50px;
}

.navbar-links {
  margin-left:10em;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0em 4em 0em 1em;
  min-width:348px;
  margin-top:auto;
  margin-bottom:auto;
}

#navbar .navbar-links a {
  display:block;
  float: left;
  color: grey;
  padding: 14px 20px 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  position:relative;
}

#navbar .navbar-links a:hover::after {
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -16px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-width: 10px 10px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey transparent;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  z-index:10;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-links">
          <a [routerLinkActive]="['navbar-links-active']" [routerLink]="['link1']" (mouseover)="displayInsightDropDown();" (mouseleave)="hideInsightDropDown();">LINK 1</a>
          <a [routerLinkActive]="['navbar-links-active']" [routerLink]="['link2']">LINK 2</a> 
          <a [routerLinkActive]="['navbar-links-active']" [routerLink]="['link3']">LINK 3</a> 
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Oh my word, thank you, can't believe I didn't catch that one :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :) Sometimes you just need to have a different pair of eyes to see the obvious :D Have a nice day!

Comment: @DanielBailey If this answer was helpful, I would appreciate an accept :)

Comment: sorry yes, I couldn't at the time because it was too soon after asking. Thank you again!